# Emberjs 1.0rc6 - Making an authenticated route

Tags: routes, ember.js

I'm trying to make it so that when you visit a given path you would be redirected to the login route.

I followed the code in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/machty/5647589), but it hasn't seemed to have any effect in my app (Everything still works the way it did before, but at least nothing broke)

My Code:

```
App.AuthenticatedRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  beforeModel: (transition) ->
    if !App.Auth.signedIn
      return RSVP.reject();

App.PromptsRoute = App.AuthenticatedRoute
  model: -> App.Prompt.find()


  error: (reason, transition) ->
    loginController = @controllerFor('login')
    loginController.set('afterLoginTransition', transition)
    @transitionTo(login)

App.LoginController = Ember.Controller.extend

  email:    null
  password: null
  remember: true
  loginError: null
  afterLoginTransition: null

  login: () ->
    self = @
    App.Auth.signIn
      data:
        email:    @get 'email'
        password: @get 'password'
        remember: @get 'remember'
    .done (response) ->
      self.clearForm()
      self.loginSucceeded()
    .fail (response) ->
      self.set('loginError', "Your username or password was incorrect. Please try again")

  clearForm: ->
    self.set('loginError', null)
    self.set('email', null)
    self.set('password', null)
    self.set('recmember', true)

  loginSucceeded: ->
    transition = @get('afterLoginTransition')
    if transition
      transition.retry()
    else
      alert("Boink")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you wanted to extend the `AuthenticatedRoute` rather than *assigning* it to your `AuthenticatedRoute`, right?

If it's the case you should do:

```
App.PromptsRoute = App.AuthenticatedRoute.extend
  model: -> App.Prompt.find()
  ...
```

Hope it helps.